# Ctrl-Super-Up after Ctrl-Super-<Left/Right> moves workspace

Tags: unity, 16.04, snap-windows

After using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> to snap a window left or right in Unity (Ubuntu 16.04), using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> subsequently moves the window to a different workspace.

I expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> to maximize a window, and it does, but only if the window is not currently snapped left or right.

Any ideas how I can fix this behavior?

Thanks.

**edit**

Apologies, this is due to bad maximize interaction with launching gnome-terminal with "--maximize".

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution that worked for me is to install [Compiz configuration settings manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/)

Go to window management and check that the Grid option is ticked. This should be all you have to do. So let's test it,
first ensure your window is maximised. Then do 
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> to shift it the left and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd> to maximise it.

But if it doesn't click on Grid and check that this Maximise Key is set up as

```
Maximise Key <Control><Super>Up
```